# No EDID whatsoever, how can I force output?

Tags: xorg

So I'm trying to get XBMCbuntu to talk to my TV, unfortunately my GPU (8800GTS) doesn't talk to the TV, it thinks it's disconnected (no EDID info at all). So far I've got it to output to the TV but can't get any resolution apart from 800x600. Xorg.0.log says:

```
(WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to validate any modes; falling back to the default mode
```

The xorg.conf and a part of the log is pastebinned [here](http://pastebin.com/LNGn5YvF). Sorry about the mess, after 6 or so hours on this I just tried the scatter gun approach putting in any option I could find.

I'm at my wits end, at one stage I had 1920x1080 by starting it with a monitor attached and switching to the TV. Unfortunately that's too high a resolution and I don't want to cart the monitor around every time I turn my media server on.

---

Edit:

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

gives [this](http://pastebin.com/B1gJRivm).

Comment: Try Change `HorizSync 30.0 - 70.0` (hsync should be around 44 for that mode) `VertRefresh 50.0 - 100.0` (vsync 74.85) , run `cvt 1280 720 60` to check

Comment: `# 1280x720 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.92M9) hsync: 44.77 kHz; pclk: 74.50 MHz
Modeline "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync`
True! I've changed it like you said but still not working. Should I go through and match the rest of the values as well?

Comment: As in, should I match the 74.50 MHz to something? The modeline is copy/pasted

Comment: Yes, Change both mode line in monitor and screen: `ModeLine       "1280x720_60.00" 74.50 1280 1344 1472 1664 720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync` and `Modes      "1280x720" "1280x720_60.00"`, 74.50 MHz should in range of `VertRefresh 50.0 - 100.0` if not you have change the range limits, same thing for HorizSync 44.77 kHz in `HorizSync 30.0 - 70.0`

Comment: `No valid modes for "DFP-1:1280x720_60.00"; removing.`
Same as before

Answer (score 0):

This is something that those of us that have picked up the Korean 1440p monitors and have Geforce cards (along with the propriety driver, using the open source driver can usually work) have run into. So we have actually a couple of questions here.

1. Does the TV REALLY have no EDID or is it just the Geforce not able to pick it up?
2. How do we recreate an EDID?

The answer to the first would really help us with the second, because we can pull the EDID via the HDMI from another means.

So, does `xrandr –prop` return anything useful? get-edid won't be of use to you unfortunately because Nvidia. If it does, you can paste that into a hex editor, call it tv-edid.bin and add a reference to it in your xorg.conf such as

```
Option “CustomEDID” “DFP:/etc/X11/tv-edid.bin”
```

You can also put it through `parse-edid < tv-edid.bin`. The chances are that there is some sort of EDID otherwise all sorts of things wouldn't work, such as blu-ray players, amps and receivers.

I've been able to get a few screens that Geforces have refused to work on going with this method.

[For reference](http://learnitwithme.com/?p=342)

Comment: `xrandr --prop` isn't particularly helpful, see here: http://pastebin.com/HgP9dkGr

Comment: I've bought a DVI-I->VGA connecter and that's working fine. In other news, anyone want a DVI->HDMI cable in Brisbane?

Comment: You appear to be using the Nvidia proprietry driver, do you get the same with nouveau?

Comment: From memory yes, it was the same. Last time I uninstalled the nvidia drivers everything broke, now that it's working with VGA I'm not sure I want to break it.

Comment: So without knowing what model your TV is and what the actual supported resolutions are it can get quite tricky. But there is an informative article at:https://www.osadl.org/Single-View.111+M591850c02b5.0.html